# Using a file as a long-term buffer

Tags: java

I am receiving an infinite stream of data as input and I am writing it to a file "out.dat". At the same time, I have to process the data with a slow function process_data(). What I would like to do is to have a thread that reads data from the file "out.dat" and processes it with process_data(). So, in the main thread, I receive the input data and write it to "out.dat", in the second I read the data from "out.dat" and process it.
(The reason for not using an exchange buffer between the two threads is that it should be quite big as the input stream is fast and process_data() is slow. Over time, the exchange buffer will grow too much.)

It seems that using [FileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) would be appropriate. In the documentation I read "The view of a file provided by an instance of this class is guaranteed to be consistent with other views of the same file provided by other instances in the same program.".
However, I am not sure since it does not specify what "consistent" really means. My need is to write data to "out.dat" and, later, from another thread, read ([FileChannel#read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#read-java.nio.ByteBuffer-long-)) the same data again. Does "consistent" mean that once I write the data, say at position 100000, when I do read(byteBuffer, 100000) I get the same data?

Do I have to call FileChannel#force to force the writings to be saved on disk?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just for the record: if you really need a long-term, robust solution, you might want to look into more advanced technologies. You know, there are many ways where one application writes something and others process that data.

Comment: I suggest you look at how Chronicle Queue https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue is implemented as it does what you are looking for by treating disk as an unbounded buffer. Each document has an index which you can replay from that index.

Comment: If the data is infinite and the consumer is slower than the producer you are going to need an infinite amount of disk space.

Comment: @EJP, yes, eventually I will seek at position 0 and start to overwrite the file.